# Creating automatic folder and files in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I wrote a groovy script in soapui to create files in certain location in my pc. How can I make it dynamic and enable the user to write the location the files are saved to by write the location in configuration file imported at test suite level.

```
if(context.expand('${#Project#ProduceReports}') == 'true') {    
    def resultDir = new File("D:\\Reports"); 
    if(!resultDir.exists()) {
        resultDir.mkdirs();
    }
    def resultsFile = new File(resultDir, "CSVReport.csv");
}
```

Comment: The path of the reports can be configured by user if project property is used. Doe it help? How are you currently loading the property file? Of course, the path can be added in your property like you already doing and let user configure it.

Comment: i defined the following   if(context.expand('${#Project#ProduceReports}') == 'true') { 
         def resultDir = new File('${#Project#Path}'); 
        if(!resultDir.exists()) {
            resultDir.mkdirs();                                                                                          and got error "Mon Oct 17 16:09:28 GMT+02:00 2016:ERROR:An error occurred: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified" although i defined a custom property at project level with the value "${#PostPaid-TCs#Path" which is read from configuration file defined at test suite level.

Comment: How is the property `Path` value defined? like `D:\\Reports`? clarify otherwise?

Comment: D:\\Reports is the value suppose for example to be read from configuration file

Comment: Is the main problem not able to create non existing directory(path is passed from a project level property)?

Comment: yes @ Rao the error i recieve is The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Do you have the `D` drive on your machine?

Comment: yes and when i add the path for example "D:\\Reports" it works

Comment: then when it does not work? By the way, can you please show complete stacktrace from error log?

Comment: when i write this in script   def resultDir = new File('${#Project#Path}');

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: iam using groovy step in soapUI

Comment: Check the answer please.

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad This `new File('${#Project#Path}');` cannot work, `#Project#Path` it's a special notation for *SOAPUI* which only works using `context.expand` --> `new File(context.expand('${#Project#Path}'))`. Your are mixing things... in groovy you can use `gstring` to evaluate vars like ```def a = 5;def s = "${a}";assert s == "5"``` but this is not the same that using SOAPUI properties.

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad finally did you find the cause of your error? Can I ask why did you accept my answer (thanks by the way :) but I'm not sure that I actually deserved it)

Comment: I am happy for you, @albciff. Finally, one more question closed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the path from a testSuite property, you can do it as you do with the project property, using `context.expand`:

```
def yourPath = context.expand('${#TestSuite#pathDirectory}')
```

Or alternatively you can do the same with:

```
def yourPath = context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('pathDirectory')
```

Maybe this is out of scope for your question, but could be helpful. If you need you can also use [`UISupport`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/UISupport.html) to ask the user to enter the path he wants with the follow code:

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
// the prompt question, title, and default value
def path = ui.prompt("Enter the path","Title","/base/path");
log.info path
```

This shows:

[image]

Comment: Actually i need the path to be added by user in configuration file which is then uploaded at custom properties at certain test suite level and want this path to be used at project level.

Answer (score 0):

Define project level custom property `REPORT_PATH` with value `D:/Reports/CSVReport.csv` i.e., full path including file and path separate by `/` slash even on windows platform.

Then use the below script to write the data.

```
//Define the content that goes as report file. Of course, you may change the content as need by you
def content = """Name,Result
Test1,passed
Test2,failed"""

//Read the project property where path is configured
def reportFileName = context.expand('${#Project#REPORT_PATH}')

//Create file object for reports
def reportFile = new File(reportFileName)

//Create parent directories if does not exists
if (!reportFile.parentFile.exists()) {
    reportFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
}

//Write the content into file
reportFile.write(content)
```

Comment: @ Rao i tried the script you sent but still getting error i just want to be able to add reference instead of actual value

Comment: def resultDir = new File('D:/Reports');  just need instead of D:/Reports want it be like ('${#Project#Report_Path}) for example is this possible with new file in groovy?

Comment: The script provided to you after the successful test. Can you show the screen shot of the error? or full stack trace?

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad This new File('${#Project#Path}'); cannot work, #Project#Path it's a special notation for SOAPUI which only works using context.expand --> new File(context.expand('${#Project#Path}')). Your are mixing things... in groovy you can use gstring to evaluate vars like def a = 5;def s = "${a}";assert s == "5" but this is not the same that using SOAPUI properties.

Comment: i tried also using context.expand and got error access denied                            def resultDir = new File(context.expand('${#Project#ReportPath}'));

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad Then `access denied` is probably due that you doesn't have the required privileges to write on `D:/Reports/CSVReport.csv`.

Comment: no i have the rights because when i just write D:/Reports/CSVReport.csv it works fine and the folder is created with csv file

Comment: Suggest you to follow the answer and comments carefully and reply with errors in detail.