# Groovy - How to create path directory with variable inside

Tags: java, groovy

I have a script in groovy to create a text file with results

My defined path file is C:/temp/SoapTest/ and I want to create dynamically a new folder , which changes in any new user test so ***I want to use a defined variable as the name of the folder*** , so the variable in this case is Affected CI .

here is my full Code:

```
nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");
def Date0 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "Date")
def DateIn = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "DateIn")
def Summary = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "Summary")
def SummaryIn = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "SummaryIn")
def RandomID = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "RandomID")
def AffectedCI = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "AffectedCI")
def SourceStatus = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "SourceStatus")
def event = 'Active-Inactive'
def INC = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "INC")
def IID_Active = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "IID Active")
def IID_Inactive = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "IID Inactive")
class LeftShiftNewlineCategory {
    static Writer leftShift(Writer self, Object value) {
        self.append value + "\n\r"
    } 
}
use(LeftShiftNewlineCategory) {
def pathfile = 'C:/temp/SoapTest/'
def subpath = 'Active-Inactive '
def fileformat = '.txt'
def FinRes = AffectedCI
def datetime = new Date().format(" dd MM yy' 'HH-mm-ss") 
def file = new File(pathfile + subpath + FinRes + datetime + fileformat).withWriter { out ->
        out << "Date:" +"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+ Date0  
        out << "${nl}DateIn:" +"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+ DateIn 
        out << "${nl}RandomID:" +"\t"+"\t"+ RandomID
        out << "${nl}AffectedCI:" +"\t"+"\t"+ AffectedCI 
        out << "${nl}SourceStatus" +"\t"+"\t"+ SourceStatus
        out << "${nl}event" +"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+ event
        out << "${nl}INC" +"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+ INC 
        out << "${nl}IID Active" +"\t"+"\t"+ IID_Active
        out << "${nl}IID Inactive" +"\t"+"\t"+ IID_Inactive 
        out << "${nl}"               
        out << "${nl}Payload:" +"\t"+"\t"+ Summary        
        out << "${nl}"               
        out << "${nl}PayloadIn:" +"\t"+"\t"+ SummaryIn
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating automatic folder and files in soapui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086411/creating-automatic-folder-and-files-in-soapui)

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need to create the parent directory(ies) first:

```
def file = new File(pathfile + subpath + FinRes + datetime + fileformat)
def success = file.parentFile.mkdirs()
println "created ${file.parentFile}: ${success}"
file.withWriter { out ->
  ...
}
```

Comment: The main parent directories are defined already . What I cant is to create the sub path folder named automatically with the variable "AffectedCI"

So if I use several different AffectedCI's in different test the groovy script will create new folders according to the AffectedCI names