# Conditional Goto based on Groovy Result response

Tags: if-statement, groovy, soapui

first of all, I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to make a groovy script to run conditionally to one or another step based on the groovy script result:

The options I want to have is 3 :

Active
Inactive 
Stop

I have a groovy script step to define a UI window to prompt like this:

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
def path = ui.prompt("Active Inactive or Stop","Title","");
def regResult = path
```

So based on what I type inside the popup window do the following:

```
If Active / Go to testRunner.gotoStepByName("InjectActive")
If Inactive / Go to testRunner.gotoStepByName("InjectInactive")
If Stop / Go to testRunner.gotoStepByName("Final Results")
```

[Image of current Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO2hx.png)

Any Ideas on how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Switch Statement in Groovy](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html) is much powerful and much more cleaner in your case:

```
def result = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Where").getPropertyValue("result")

switch (result) {
    case "Active": testRunner.gotoStepByName("InjectActive"); break 
    case "Inactive": testRunner.gotoStepByName("InjectInactive"); break
    case "Stop": testRunner.gotoStepByName("Final Results"); break
    // in case result is null or empty
    case {!it}: testRunner.gotoStepByName("result is null or empty"); break
    // handle any other values
    default: testRunner.gotoStepByName("Unexpected value")
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you @bitsnaps 

I have another thread open maybe you have some tips?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882688/groovy-how-to-create-path-directory-with-variable-inside

Answer (score 0):

I realized how to do it:

```
def result = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Where").getPropertyValue("result")

if (result == ("Active")) {
  testRunner.gotoStepByName("InjectActive")
} 
else if (result == ("Inactive")){
  testRunner.gotoStepByName("InjectInactive")
}
else if (result == ("Stop")){
  testRunner.gotoStepByName("Final Results")
}
```